# Datepicker - set minDate based on the value of another element

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to set the `datepicker` `minDate` property based on the value of another element.

I am using this:

```
$("input[name='selection_itv_date']").click(function() {

    var min_date_for_itv = $(this).closest('.selection').siblings('.application').find("input[name='job_receiving_date']").val();

    $("input[name='selection_itv_date']").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(min_date_for_itv),
        yearRange: "-1:+0"
    });
});
```

I need to get the value of `input[name='job_receiving_date']` on click because I have multiple inputs with this name on the page.
I tried using `onSend` but no results.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What value are you getting for `min_date_for_itv`? Is it a valid date string?

Comment: The string format is '19 Apr 2016'. Yes, it is a valid string value.

Comment: Are you having trouble setting the minDate or getting the value from the input?

Comment: Setting the `minDate` to the value I'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code works, but it requires 2 clicks.  That's because the first click just initialises the input as a datepicker, nothing else.  If you then click away on your page, and click back into the input, you'll see the datepicker appear, since it is now a datepicker, with your minDate correct.  Try it!

Obviously that's not very good UX :-)  A quick fix is to simply call [the `show` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show) right after you initialise the datepicker:

```
$("input[name='selection_itv_date']").click(function() {
    var min_date_for_itv = ...
    $("input[name='selection_itv_date']").datepicker({
        ...
    });

    $("input[name='selection_itv_date']").datepicker('show');
});
```

A neater option might be to initialise your datepicker independent of the click, say on document ready, and update the `minDate` option on click:

```
$("input[name='selection_itv_date']").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min_date_for_itv);
```

Though having just tried that it looks like the click handler interferes with the datepicker and it doesn't display correctly.  If the user is selecting `min_date_for_itv`, best would be to trigger the update to your datepicker on the change of *that* input:

```
$("input[name='job_receiving_date']").on('change', function() {
    $("input[name='selection_itv_date']").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min_date_for_itv);
});
```

As an aside, if you are using a selector more than once, it's a good idea to cache it:

```
var $datepicker = $("input[name='selection_itv_date']");

$datepicker.datepicker({ ... });
$datepicker.datepicker('show');
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are setting the `minDate` for all the inputs once one is clicked. You should be setting the `minDate` for the input currently clicked instead.

If you change the line

```
$("input[name='selection_itv_date']").datepicker({
```

to

```
$("this").datepicker({
```

, it will just create the datepicker on-the-fly for that input.

Comment: I already tried it and the `datepicker` could not be triggered.

Comment: @F.Gran Have you tried calling the [show()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show) method? First assign the created datepicker to a variable, then call `.datepicker("show")` on that object.